# Android service communication, with Raw bytes over SSL

Tags: android, web-services, sockets, ssl

I have given a 3rd party API to access a service to get some work done from a client Android App.

There they have provided  **Service hosted URL** and the **PORT number** and asking to send raw bytes (Request data) over a SSL IP Socket connection to it.

Steps they Ask to follow

1. Open a SSL connection to Service. The SSL Connection will be mutually authenticated. (Self signed certificate)
2. Send request data in a CSV structure format (Raw bytes over a SSL IP Socket connection).
3. The App now will receive a response (byte stream) from the SSL connection.

**Questions**

1. Is this a standard way to do in Android?
2. I have previousely communicated with web services by sending request data over HTTP/S (POST and GET) methods but wonder how to do this. Read many tutorials ([LINK1](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)) but still bit not exactly sure how to do this.

Would like to here what exactly(steps) I have to do in here. Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SSL is standard practice on any platform that needs to protect data.  It has nothing to do with Android specifically.

In an Android client app, you can use the [`SSLSocket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) class.  It will handle the SSL portion for you, so all you have to focus on is sending the CSV data and reading the response data.

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau. Is it a good practice to access the services in this way (Using SSLSocket in the TCP layer) comparing to http communication? I know http is on top of TCP but not sure if this is a good way to deal with the service... Thanks.

Comment: Many services are moving towards HTTP/REST interfaces for convenience and easy access, but that is not to say that custom non-HTTP/REST interfaces can't still be created/used. clearly, you are trying to access a non-HTTP service, so use whatever is needed to access it.